# How to work with the third party COM object(IOPCDataCallback) created by CWinThread::AfxBeginThread()

Tags: multithreading, com

I create a CwinThread::thread in my application in order to get access to the data in COM asynchronous CALLBACK function.the COM library is initialized by CoInitialize(NULL).
Then when the thread uses the COM object's function an error occurred:

> Method call IOPCAsyncIO2::Write failed with error code 8001010e

I use **Error Lookup** for help:the application is calling an Interface which is organized by another thread
the thread is supposed to be the COM thread.
any ideas?

sorry for not giving you the specific codes few days ago. This time I want to describe my issue using the pseudo code:
first:

> `in class A,func1
>   r1 = CoInitialize(NULL);
>   then something for judgement`

in class B(this class is created as a winthread and used for accessing the data from callback class take CallbackClass as example).

```
in class A,I initialize the thread by calling 
m_pThread = AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(CTestThread), THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,0,NULL);
```

calling the functions of Class B by

```
m_pThread->PostThreadMessage(WM_INITIALIZETHREAD, (WPARAM)this, 0);
```

one can be aware that the Class A is set for just coding and building the relationship between the dialog, Class B and the CallbackClass.
My question is: I have read many blogs about the MTA and STA, and I know my PC's HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT says the ThreadingModel is Apartment. When I use the Class B(Thread class) to get the pointer of the CallbackClass,there the issue happens.
I know there must be something I missed about my thread and I need some example of at least one COM initialization and one win32 thread and how the thread can get access COM's data.Thank you very much.

Comment: 8001010e (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD) means some code has a pointer (to an object's COM interface) that was created on one thread and tries to call a method (on this pointer) in another thread. It depends on your specific code, but you mention callbacks, and that's a lead.

Comment: One does not simply pass a COM pointer between threads. See [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/150777) for details.

Comment: @simon-mourier thanks a lot. I mean the client thread's pointer tries to call the method(this method is the interface of COM object).
'CComObject<COPCDataCallback>* pCOPCDataCallback; // Pointer to Callback Object

 // Create Instance of Callback Object using an ATL template
 HRESULT hresult;

 hresult = CComObject<COPCDataCallback>::CreateInstance(&pCOPCDataCallback);'
the interface 'STDMETHODIMP COPCDataCallback::OnDataChange()'

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for your help. It is really helpful.

Comment: Difficult to help more. You should put a full repro code.

Comment: @SimonMourier thank you.I have just added my code on it .Please help me out .

Answer (score 1):

So, you're sending a "raw" COM interface ('this') to code in another thread. That's probably why you get the error.

COM interface pointers must be passed using COM methods (as arguments to the method so COM knows it has to marshal it to another thread/apartment), not by other means. When in apartment model, you think of it like every COM object lives in each own process (you can't use 'this' in another process, and that's the same rule for apartments).

You could use "COM Connection points" (see here + google for some explanations: [An introduction to COM connection points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/11/10424940.aspx)) which are like events between COM objects. Note this can be complicated.

You could also use more low-level constructs and marshal interface pointers yourself (using [the CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693316.aspx)). See another article on this here: [What are the rules for CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream and CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/10/21/10649190.aspx). I would try that first.

Comment: awesome! Thank you very much.